# SQL query structure - variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, ssms

I have a query where I want to include a new variable. I need the query to check if this variable returns NULL, and if it does, exclude the record from the resultset.

The variable I need to incorporate is `@PaymentStatusID_DV` but I don't know where to put it where it would make sense. To assign it is this:

```
SELECT @PaymentStatusID_DV = dbo.fnGetSimpleDvByThirdPartyField(c.ClientID,c.CustomerID,l.LeadID,ca.CaseID,m.MatterID,1490,4370)
```

So where can I put that in within this query and then check for the NULL? (IS NOT NULL)

```
DECLARE @SettlementDate DATE, 
        @PaymentStatusID_DV VARCHAR(2000),
        @ClientID = 384

SELECT @SettlementDate=dbo.fnAddWorkingDays ( dbo.fnGetNextWorkingDate (CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()),0) ,cdv.ValueInt + 1 ) 
FROM ClientDetailValues cdv WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE cdv.DetailFieldID=170226 AND cdv.ClientID=@ClientID

SELECT
c.CustomerID,ca.CaseID,ca.LatestInProcessLeadEventID [LeadEventID],m.MatterID, COUNT(m.MatterID)
FROM Customers c WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Lead l WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.CustomerID=l.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Cases ca WITH (NOLOCK) ON l.LeadID=ca.LeadID
INNER JOIN Matter m WITH (NOLOCK) ON ca.CaseID=m.CaseID
LEFT JOIN MatterDetailValues suspended WITH (NOLOCK) ON m.MatterID=suspended.MatterID AND suspended.DetailFieldID=175275
INNER JOIN LeadTypeRelationship ltr WITH (NOLOCK) ON ltr.ToMatterID=m.MatterID AND ltr.FromLeadTypeID=1492 AND ltr.ToLeadTypeID=1493
INNER JOIN Matter pam WITH (NOLOCK) ON ltr.FromMatterID=pam.MatterID
INNER JOIN CustomerPaymentSchedule cps WITH (NOLOCK) ON cps.CustomerID = c.CustomerID AND cps.WhenCreated > '2017-09-01'
INNER JOIN Account a WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.AccountID = cps.AccountID
WHERE  c.Test=0 AND c.ClientID=@ClientID
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM LeadEvent le WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE le.CaseID=ca.CaseID AND le.EventDeleted=0 AND le.EventTypeID=155198 ) -- and collections are not on hold
AND (suspended.ValueInt <> 5144 OR suspended.ValueInt IS NULL) -- and policy status is live
AND cps.CustomerLedgerID IS NULL -- and payment schedule entry has not already been queued in the GL
AND cps.ActualCollectionDate <= @SettlementDate -- and payment date is before or the same as settlement day
AND cps.PaymentGross < 0 -- exclude zero value payments
AND a.AccountTypeID=1 -- and this is a DD payment
GROUP BY c.CustomerID,ca.CaseID,ca.LatestInProcessLeadEventID,m.MatterID
```

Comment: Too much to read... Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude **it** from the resultset?"  What's it here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: If a record hits all of the other criteria, but does not have an @PaymentStatusID_DV, then I do not want the record to return

Comment: You might want to read up on nolock before you continue splattering it all over the place. It says you are ok with your data being mostly correct most of the time. And for things like payments it is absolutely unacceptable. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @SeanLange This is the standard with our company. We have clients who query some parts of our data with our interface so it's necessary to prevent tables from getting locked.

Comment: Well that is downright horrible. This query appears to be pulling financial information. Just because it is a standard does NOT mean it is a good decision. That hint means you will randomly get missing and/or duplicate rows. This is a major problem when deal with things that need to be accurate. I understand it probably outside of your ability to change but you should understand the problems with that hint. I did some consulting for a client that used that hint everywhere, it cost them several million dollars to undo it when they realized how bad it really was.

Comment: And if you have a policy that forces you to use that hint you should just set the isolation level in your procedures instead. Will save you thousands of characters typing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use the variable? The best way would be to include the function in your WHERE statement:

```
WHERE ... AND dbo.fnGetSimpleDvByThirdPartyField(c.ClientID,c.CustomerID,l.LeadID,ca.CaseID,m.MatterID,1490,4370) IS NOT NULL
```